# Coerce field to Bag datatype in Pig

Tags: casting, hadoop, apache-pig

Say I'm loading in a bag into Pig without a schema file. I know that each tuple in the bag contains 1 field, which is also a bag, e.g.

```
{
  ({1, 2, 3}),
  ({3,4,5}),
  ({1,2})
}
```

I would like to cast each tuple's first argument into a bag. How can I do so?

```
data = LOAD '/path/to/data' AS (f:bytearray);
data2 = FOREACH data GENERATE (bag)f;  -- this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = LOAD '/path/to/data' AS (f:bag{(n:int)});
```